# How to install a shared library when installing to a system path?

Tags: make, shared-library

I am experimenting with how to distribute a simple graphics library for Linux using a `Makefile`. The shared library is called `libsgtk.so`. Here is my first attempt for the `Makefile`:

```
CFLAGS= -pthread \
       -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 \
       -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 \
       -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 \
       -I/usr/include/cairo \
       -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 \
       -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 \
       -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include

all: libsgtk.so

libsgtk.so: window.o
    gcc -shared -o libsgtk.so window.o

window.o: window.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c -fpic window.c

clean:
     rm window.o

install:
    mv libsgtk.so /usr/local/lib
```

As you can see, I have hard coded the installation path to `/usr/local/lib`. Is this a recommended approach?
What should I do if a library with the same name already exists in that path? 
Should this be checked in the Makefile, or is there some other tools that I should use that could provide me with an alternative installation path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use variables. For example:

```
DESTDIR?=/usr/local/lib
...
install:
  mv libsgtk.so ${DESTDIR}
```

In this case the user can overwrite the default value with `make DESTDIR=/usr/lib` (note the `?` above).

If you want you can test it. Maybe it's not a bad idea. The simplier method is to use `mv -n` (or `mv -nv`) instead of `mv`: doesn't overwrite the existing file. Its main drawback the return value of `mv` is zero so the `make` will not know that the moving wasn't success.

But if you would use `cp` (copy) instead of `mv` it will be good: the `cp -n` is return 1 (nonzero) when the destination file exists. So the solution (test included):

```
install:
  cp -n libsgtk.so ${DESTDIR}
```

Only a helping question: do you know about `PHONY` targets in `Makefile`? You should use it for `install` and `clean` targets (remark: you should delete `libsgtk.so` too in `clean`).

Comment: It would be more in line with how other installation software works to set `PREFIX?=/usr/local` and then install the library in `"$PREFIX/lib`. Also, the `install` utility may be useful here instead of `cp`.

Comment: Yes, of course. But would better with `LIBDIR=${PREFIX}/lib` :)

Comment: Or, just write the `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` files from the start... :-)